# UPDATE with EXISTS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, erp

I'm testing this UPDATE statement to update all 4%, 8%, and 9% parts in our database. I'm trying to get the QTY_MULTIPLE value to match the CASES per layer value.

So, the REGEXP_LIKE, will eventually read:

```
> Regexp_like ( sp.part_no, '^4|^8|^9' )
```

It doesn't right now because I'm testing three specific parts. I want to make sure the rest of the statement works the way that it's supposed to.

Here's what I'm testing with:

```
UPDATE SALES_PART_TAB sp
SET    sp.qty_multiple = ( SELECT cases_per_layer
                           FROM   HH_INV_PART_CHARS
                           WHERE  sp.part_no = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.part_no AND
                                  sp.contract = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.contract )
WHERE  Regexp_like ( sp.part_no, '^410-0017|^816-0210|^921-0003' ) AND
       EXISTS
       ( SELECT sp.contract,
       sp.part_no,
       sp.qty_multiple,
       HH_INV_PART_CHARS.cases_per_layer
         FROM   SALES_PART sp
                inner join HH_INV_PART_CHARS
                        ON sp.part_no = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.part_no AND
                           sp.contract = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.contract
         WHERE  sp.qty_multiple != HH_INV_PART_CHARS.cases_per_layer );
```

When I run this statement, it updates 16 rows.

However, I'm expecting it to update 15 rows. I reached this conclusion by running the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT sp.contract,
       sp.catalog_no,
       sp.qty_multiple,
       HH_INV_PART_CHARS.cases_per_layer
FROM   SALES_PART sp
       inner join HH_INV_PART_CHARS
               ON sp.part_no = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.part_no AND
                  sp.contract = HH_INV_PART_CHARS.contract
WHERE  sp.qty_multiple != HH_INV_PART_CHARS.cases_per_layer AND
       Regexp_like ( sp.part_no, '^410-0017|^816-0210|^921-0003' )
```

I *think* the problem I'm having is the UPDATE statement is updating all rows where the part_no and contract from the sales_part table exist on HH_INV_PART_CHARS. It's not limiting the update to part where the qty_multiple isn't equal to the cases_per_layer (which is what I want).

I'm a little stumped right now. I've been trying to work on both the subqueries but I'm not having any luck identifying where the problem is.

Comment: The `Regexp_like ( sp.part_no,...)` in the `update` query refers to `SALES_PART_TAB.spart_no`, while in the second query it refers to `SALES_PART.spart_no`. One of the causes of the fog is that you redefine the alias `sp` in the same query, and so the `exists` subquery does not relate in *any* way to the record that is being updated. This means that if you would throw away the `exists` condition, you would still update 16 records. It seems very unlikely that this is what you want.

Comment: That did it. Thanks for clearing that up.

Comment: OK, I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The `Regexp_like ( sp.part_no,...)` in the update query refers to `SALES_PART_TAB.spart_no`, while in the second query it refers to `SALES_PART.spart_no`.

One of the causes of the fog is that you redefine the alias `sp` in the same query, and so the `exists` subquery does not relate in any way to the record that is being updated. This means that if you would throw away the `exists` condition, you would still update 16 records. It seems very unlikely that this is what you want.

Use a different alias, so you can distinguish which table you want to refer to.